# Replace transaction body with xml file content

Tags: xml, apache-camel, jbossfuse

In a JBoss fuse route I need to replace the transaction body with the contents of an XML file that I have in my fuse project.

I tried the following code:

```
<log message="Before"/>
<to uri="language:constant:gr/xxx/yyy/fuse/zzz/xslt/common/mapping.xml"/>
<log message="After"/>
<log message="${body}" />
```

And I get the following logs from fuse

```
Before
Endpoint[language://constant:gr/xxx/yyy/fuse/zzz/xslt/common/mapping.xml]
Evaluated expression as: gr/xxx/yyy/fuse/zzz/xslt/common/mapping.xml
After
gr/xxx/yyy/fuse/zzz/xslt/common/mapping.xml
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? There is a chance that Language is not supported for my Apache Camel version, but I can't be sure what the version is. Is there another way to do this for Apache Camel older than 2.2 for example?

Answer (score 0):

try to  add resource:file or resource:classpath to read the file. Otherwise constant will only set you string to the body.

see https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/constant-language.html for more information.